# Backing up a welder's power source with lead acid batteries

Tags: power-electronics, battery, welding

I'm thinking of purchasing a MIG welder sometime in the future. Given, the ordinary mains cannot supply the power. So I would have to plug it through the dryer's outlet, with some adapter & extension, as needed. Although this can take a bit of power toll on the extension, depending on the distance. Also, I may want to do the welding well outside the house.

So how hard is it to rig most welding machines to run off car batteries to supplement a weak outlet (but not thoroughly be drawing from it wholly). I understand each design are different, but I know enough electronics. And, if the power conditionings part are pretty much standard to many products, I'm willing to go for it.

Comment: I knew someone who used a UPS in a remote location - drove home , charged came back to weld. Als ran his light and grinder.

Comment: there are purpose-buil pattery powered wleders.  Using a battery to pwoer an inverter to power a welder will require quite an effort just to get the components right, and to provide the rquired power for the batteries.  I think you would really struggle to power a 225 amp Lincoln tombstone at full power.  There are vehicle alternator-powered welders used in offroading.